# Предложение закрыть вопрос дубликатом

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Хотел закрыть этот вопрос [return срабатывает раньше img.onload?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817291/return-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-img-onload) по причине "этот вопрос уже был задан и имеет решение…". Мне система предложила список вопросов, предполагаемых дубликатов. Первым вопросом шел этот [Как вернуть значение из асинхронной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513037/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), который уже закрыт как дубликат.

Если система определяет, что можно закрыть вопрос каким-то вопросом дубликатом, но этот вопрос в свою очередь был закрыт как дубликат, то может имеет смысл предлагать самый основной вопрос опуская цепочку закрытых дубликатов? Или, если не опускать, то предлагать всю цепочку **вместе** с основным вопросом?

Или, если цепочка зациклена, отображать все вопросы из этой цепочки с сортировкой по убыванию голосов за вопрос

Comment: Вы предполагаете, что цепочка не зациклена в кольцо, буквой "О" или буквой "Р". В самом простом случае. А когда начинают переделывать старые дубликаты на более новый ответ - такое гарантированно случится.

Comment: @AK Вы правы. Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @AK, а разве можно зациклить?

Comment: @Qwertiy похоже, что таки нельзя зациклить. При попытке зациклить появляется ошибка https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpqkJ.png

Comment: @AK система не дает зациклить